# Can not get column headers for WinTable in coded ui

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am testing a winform application and I want to get column headers of a table. I tried to use methods of UITesting.WinControls but it shows me class path instead of colum names.
I tried Column Headers, getColumsn so far but couldnt get column names.

Below code brings me  this ->
Microsfost.VisualStudio.TestTools,UITesting.UITestControlCollection

```
        WinTable uIG1Table = this.UIProMANAGEWindow.UIMakineListesiWindow.UIG1Window.UIG1Table;

        MessageBox.Show(uIG1Table.ColumnHeaders.ToString());
```

Below code brings this -> System.String[]

```
        MessageBox.Show(uIG1Table.GetColumnNames().ToString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `System.String[]` is telling that you have an array of strings. To get the individual column names you need to index into the array. Try code such as:

```
string allHeaders = "";
foreach (string header in uIG1Table.ColumnHeaders)
{
    allHeaders += header + ", ";
}
MessageBox.Show(allHeaders);
```

also:

```
string allHeaders = "";
for (int index=0; index<uIG1Table.ColumnHeaders.Length; index++)
{
    allHeaders += index + ":" + uIG1Table.ColumnHeaders[index] + ", ";
}
MessageBox.Show(allHeaders);
```

Comment: When I try this -> foreach (string header in uIG1Table.ColumnHeaders.ToString()), says can not convert char to string ?

Comment: @RasimAvci Delete the `.ToString()` part of the `foreach (string header in uIG1Table.ColumnHeaders.ToString())` code in your comment. Use the code shown in my answer.

Comment: Already tried that., gives syntax error bcos of string header when toString not used -> Cannot convert type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl' to 'string'. and there is no Length property for ColumnHeaders